# print and return python

Tags: python, return

I want to print and return a value, but cant seem to find my way around it.
I have this as of now:

```
def collatz_number(n):
# If n is not a positive integer
    if n<=0:
        return "Only positive integers please"


# Even numbers
    elif n % 2 == 0:
        return n // 2


# If n is 1
    elif n == 1:
        return 1


# Odd number
    elif n % 2 == 1:
        return 3*n+1
```

I want it to function like this:

```
>>>a = collatz_number(5)
```

16

```
>>> print(a)
```

16

My problem is that I either print 16 two times, if I use print under each if statement (the code would then print the same number the if statement returns), or as it is with this code that you see - I only get 16 after print(a), but not after a = collatz_number(n).

How can I make this code function as I stated above: have it print and return the collatz number of n such that it works like this(as stated above):

```
>>> a = collatz_number(n)
```

16

```
>>> print(a)
```

16

Im sorry for the bad formulation

Comment: The last condition is excessive, you can change the elif into else.

Answer (score 4):

You almost never want to print from a function. If you *don't* want the return value printed, there's nothing (easy) you can do about it. If you *do* want it printed, you can always do so after the function returns the value. If for some reason you *must* both print and return, save the return value to a variable so that you only need *one* `return` statement, which can be preceded by a single call to `print`.

Unrelated, but don't return strings to indicate errors from functions that otherwise return numbers. Raise an exception instead.

```
def collatz_number(n):
    if n <= 0:
        raise ValueError("Only positive integers please")

    if n == 1:
        rv = 1
    elif n % 2 == 0:
        rv = n // 2   
    else:
        rv = 3*n+1

    # print(rv)
    return rv
```

Check for `n==1` first, to avoid doing an unnecessary division. Also, a number is either even or odd; if `n % 2 != 0`, you *know* it is 1; you don't need to do the division again.

Answer (score 0):

You can just print the variable inside of the function before returning it.

```
def foo(x):
    return_value= x+5
    print(return_value)
    return return_value
a=foo(10)
```

Answer (score 0):

The 'return' statement doesn't print anything, you can only store that returned value into a variable, and then print it. 
I'm not sure if I understand your question.. but the case is that, if you want to print twice, as you show in your example you have to do this:

```
def collatz_number(n):
# If n is not a positive integer
    if n<=0:
        print "Only positive integers please"
        return -1 #for example, you could return any other value..


# Even numbers
    elif n % 2 == 0:
        print str(n // 2)
        return n // 2


# If n is 1
    elif n == 1:
        print str(1)
        return 1


# Odd number
    elif n % 2 == 1:
        print str(3*n+1)
        return 3*n+1
```

observe that to print a number you have to convert it to 'str' type first... So, you cant't do print (a), but instead do print (str(a))

I hope my answer helps! Good luck!